# Server 18.04: netplan, avahi and DHCP combination

Tags: networking, server, avahi, netplan

For a long time now I have been looking for a means to replicate Window's IPv4 assignment behaviour. That is, first try DHCP and on failure switch to link-local addressing. So far I failed to find anything applicable to Ubuntu.

Now that 18.04 is out I wanted to give to see if this new netplan of theirs could be of any use to help achieve my goal. But, to me its a confusing mess of a program with way too limited documentation about it. All I can find are examples about DHCP and static addressing. Even some talk on VLANs and bridging. But nothing about link-local addressing.

How can I combine netplan, DHCP and Avahi in a manner similar to Windows?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask *one question*, so you can receive *one answer*.  When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question!  **;-)** So please, split up your question into multiple questions

Comment: Okay, done. I kept the main question in this one and put my sub-questions into posts of their own.

Comment: Thank you.  2 more votes required to reopen as I'm writing this.